# Joomla category list fields

Tags: php, joomla

I am using the category list view which outputs a sortable table with "Title", "Author" and "Hits".

I was wondering if I can add extra fields to this table I wanted some other fields like "City", "Country" etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: Where would you get the information from? Are you entering City, Country, etc somewhere?

Comment: For com_contact?  The basic problem is this, for sorting you really need a field that can be directly queried, so fields you add in say a json string are not going to work for those sortable lists.

Comment: The fields do not currently exist but I would like to add them.